# navigation bar back button repeated

Tags: ios, back-button, navigationbar

I have a tableView with push segue to a detailView, and in this second view a button that perform a segue to a map location.

My problem is the back button of navigation bar appear twice (different icons also) in the map location view.

I guess is something of pushing twice the navigationbar, but I can't resolve it.

and this the method that I use to perform segues, to the detail view first

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue_ID"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //here I pass info between views

        DetailView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;       
    }
}
```

and to the map:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMap"]) {

        MapViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       //here I pass info between views

        vc.object = self.object;

    }
}
```

Any help? please

Comment: Neither can we with no code nor picture of storyboard etc.

Comment: added code, I can not post images yet. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put in LeftBarButtonItem, and also BackButtonItem for your nav bar?

Try making one of them nil.